# SQL Escape for access database from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-jet-ace

Which characters need to be escaped before being inserted into a JET Engine data table? I'm currently just replacing the ' character for this '' (this are two ' characters, not a " character) and it works just fine (I'm quoting the string with the ' character like this 'hello' so I'd turn this: 'don't' into this 'don''t' ).

So far it has been working fine, but is there any other character I need to escape? I'm creating these queries from C# code and executing them with a `OleDbCommand`.

**Edit** I know I can use parametrized queries. But I would like to know the answer to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning ' into '' is enough. Every other character can stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

Rather use parameterized queries.  The provider would solve all these issues for you.